# How to create fullscreen activity with toolbar like inshort app?

Tags: android-activity, android-toolbar, android-fullscreen

I want to create layout with full screen and toolbar above so that when I click on navigation drawable icon and overflow icon a screen open with the same effect given in app inshorts .

[image]

when I touch on screen the toolbar view disappear
[image]

it seems like it is not action bar above the screen because overflow icon and drawable icon click feature is different

Please help me to create that type of activity with  toolbar and with same effect given in application.

you can find the link of the app [inshorts app link is here](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.nis.app&hl=en)

Answer (score 0):

Please follow below steps:

**Step 1 :** Created new project with navigation drawer template

[image]

**Step 2 :** Open app_bar_mai.xml and Change Coordinator layout to FrameLayout

[image]

**Step 3** Remove app bar layout and give semi transparent background color to Toolbar. [For semi transparent color Use #CCffffff]

**Step 4 :** Design the layout as per you requirement. If you want to hide action bar same like inshort app use below code in onclick event of main layout.

### if (getSupportActionBar().isShowing()) { getSupportActionBar().hide(); } else { getSupportActionBar().show(); }

**Step 5 :** That's it. You will get layout same like Inshot app.